# android.text.format.Time class initialization in Robolectric Environment

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I'm facing an Exception while initializing an instance of `android.text.format.Time` class ( `Time time = new Time()` ) in *Robolectric* (Unit Test) Environment. How I can configure this unit test environment to bypass this problem?

Here's the configuration I'm using for my unit test -

```html
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(sdk = 28)
@PowerMockIgnore({"org.mockito.*", "android.*", "org.json.*})
```

And here's the exception I'm getting -

```html
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at android.text.format.Time$TimeCalculator.lookupZoneInfo(Time.java:1110)
    at android.text.format.Time$TimeCalculator.__constructor__(Time.java:1070)
    at android.text.format.Time$TimeCalculator.<init>(Time.java)
    at android.text.format.Time.initialize(Time.java:208)
    at android.text.format.Time.__constructor__(Time.java:184)
    at android.text.format.Time.<init>(Time.java)
    ........
        ........
   
 org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement$1.run(PowerMockRule.java:83)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(WhiteboxImpl.java:1854)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:816)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:681)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:401)
    at org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.getResult(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:76)
    at org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.invokeWithClassLoader(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:64)
    at org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.executeWithClassLoader(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:56)
    at org.powermock.classloading.SingleClassloaderExecutor.execute(SingleClassloaderExecutor.java:33)
    at org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.execute(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:40)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement.evaluate(PowerMockRule.java:75)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:546)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$0(SandboxTestRunner.java:252)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:89)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```